# Visual Studio Throws Error: There is no editor available for <Crystal Report>.rpt

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

> **Environment: Windows 7; Crystal Report 13.0.6; Visual Studio 2012;**

There were just some reports in my VS Project which I could not open and throws an error as:

[image]

> **Note:** 
>   This project was a migration from VS 2005 to VS 2012 and Crystal Reports to Visual Studio.NET to SAP Crystal Report Developer Version for Visual Studio.NET 13.0.6.

Comment: this http://scn.sap.com/thread/3331626 might help

Comment: @GSiry, I have installed the runtime, and Crystal Reports are working fine, but in the design time only certain reports are throwing this error message. Others are fine where I could open those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by my self. Answer is what I responded in SAP Crystal Report Forum [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3402009)

Answer (score 0):

We have been unable to reproduce the issue you are seeing. One possible workaround is to try to reset your Visual Studio settings. From the command line, navigate to the \Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ and run 'devenv.exe /resetsettings'.
MKGT( SOURAV KUMAR KAR )